# What causes "double free or corruption" and "invalid pointer" in javacpp - ffmpeg?

Tags: java, c++, ffmpeg, h.264, decoding

I use https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/ffmpeg

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
      <artifactId>ffmpeg</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2-1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

When i am calling avformat_open_input/avformat_close_input i randomly (never at first call) get those errors :

```
 Error in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fe79c194aa0
```

or

```
Error in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00007fe51c3ffb60
```

or

```
Error in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00007fcdc40fe4a0
```

I cant find out how to solve this, please help.

There is my implementation :

```
    private static void registerComponents() {
        if (!componentsRegistered) {
            componentsRegistered = true;
            av_register_all();
        }
    }

    public static void decodeFrame(ByteBuffer frameData) {
        registerComponents();

        AVFormatContext pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
        int i, videoStream;
        AVCodecContext pCodecCtx = null;
        AVCodec pCodec = null;
        AVFrame pFrame = null;
        AVFrame pFrameRGB = null;

        int[] frameFinished = new int[1];
        int numBytes;
        BytePointer buffer = null;

        AVDictionary    optionsDict = null;
        SwsContext      sws_ctx = null;

        AVIOContext ioContext = avio_alloc_context(new BytePointer(frameData), frameData.capacity(), 0, null, null, null, null);
        pFormatCtx.pb(ioContext);

        if (avformat_open_input(pFormatCtx, "", null, null) < 0) {
            logger.error(MarkerFactory.getMarker("ffmpeg"), "Problem with load video from memory.");
            return;
        }

       avformat_close_input(pFormatCtx);       
    }
```

Comment: You could open a ticket here https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ if you don't get a good answer now.